# Search box like w3schools.com

Tags: search, web

I want to make a simple searchbox in my website. I think for my situation, the best way is to use something like w3schools.com did. When user types smth and press enter it redirects to google.com/search  and it will search from only w3schools.com  in google because there is site:www.w3schools.com is given in url. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="get" name="searchform" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="text" name="as_q" size="20" value="Search stackoverflow.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" title="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But you should also check this out:
http://www.google.com/cse/

Answer (score 0):

Just browse source code and take everything you need, that trick will often do in case of HTML how-to's:

```
<form method="get" name="searchform" action="http://www.google.com/search" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="www.yoursite.com">
    <input type="text" name="as_q" size="20" value="Search yoursite.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Search" title="Search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well. Actually it seems this is quite easy job. I have found the solution At:
http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_can_i_add_a_google_search_box_to_my_web_site.html/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is **Google Custom Search Engine**. Start here: http://www.google.com/cse/docs/ , http://www.google.com/cse/manage/all